# Latest ARM processors that are not BGA

Tags: arm

I am looking for an ARM, preferably with an MMU, that is not in a BGA package so hobbyists reflow it at home.

Comment: See also http://chiphacker.com/questions/2704/cheapest-arm-with-an-mmu (AT91, imx233)

Answer (score 15):

[Cavium Networks ECONA family](http://www.caviumnetworks.com/processor_ECONA-ARM.html) has several ARM922-based processors with MMUs that run at 200-250 MHz. They have a PQFP 128-pin package. I think they're the most powerful non-BGA ARMs you can get (so far as I know).

PQFP packages are still pretty hairy to solder, so you might also look at the [NXP 17xx series](http://ics.nxp.com/products/lpc1000/lpc17xx/) of Cortex M3 chips, which run at 100 MHz. Unfortunately, the M3 core does *not* have an MMU. I don't know all the packages used, but at least the LPC1758 comes in a LQFP 80-pin package with 0.5 mm pitch. You could also check the LPC2xxx series, but I'm not familiar with them.

If that's still too tricky, NXP has announced an ARM Cortex M0 chip, the LPC1114, that will be available in a 44-pin PLCC package in Q4 of 2010 (that is, you can't buy it for a few months yet). It only runs at 50 MHz and it has no MMU, but PLCCs can use through-hole sockets that can be soldered by hand pretty easily.

**update** (2011-07-28, by stevenvh)
We're now 2011Q3, and there's no sign of a PLCC [LPC1114](http://ics.nxp.com/products/lpc1000/datasheet/lpc1111.lpc1112.lpc1113.lpc1114.pdf); it's only available as LQFP48 and leadless HVQFN33. Frankly, it would have surprised me to see it in PLCC; it's an archaic and big package (height: 5mm!), which these days won't get many customers.

Comment: @Kevin Boyd: Thank you, sir! I've recently built a small Linux board using an ARM processor, so I was trying to answer the same question.

If anyone else knows of candidates that rival the Cavium Networks chips, I'd love to know about them. (I went with an Atmel BGA chip in the end, the AT91SAM9G20.)

Comment: Something to beware of - I think that the NXP M0s don't support JTAG, so you may need to invest in an SWD tool

Comment: Any idea of a chip having an Arm9 core with 12bit adc and 12bit stereo dac?

Comment: @Kevin Boyd: I don't know of any ARM9's with on-chip DACs. They might exist, but I've not seen one. The Freescale i.MX233 might be your best bet-- 12-bit ADC plus dual serial audio interfaces on chip.

Answer (score 5):

Another to consider is the [Cirrus Logic EP9302](http://www.cirrus.com/en/products/pro/detail/P1066.html)

- 208 LQFP
- ARM9
- USB Host
- Ethernet MAC

Answer (score 3):

I did some research recently when I was choosing the fastest ARM MCU that I could find and solder myself.

My vote is definitely i.MX233:

http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=i.MX233

ARM926EJ-S™, 454 MHz maximum speed
128 LQFP - small but manageable

This might be useful place for research:
http://www.embeddeddeveloper.com/

This is a search for MCUs faster than 300MHz and supporting DDR memory:

http://www.embeddeddeveloper.com/search/?form_manufacturer[]=Any&form_bit=Any&form_instruction[]=10&form_variant=Any&form_frequency=300MHz&form_flash=Any&form_features[]=&form_features[]=&form_features[]=&form_features[]=&form_i2c=&form_can=&form_usb=&form_eth=&form_ad=&form_pci=&form_ddr=any&processor_part_number=Processor+Part+Number&keyword_search=Keyword&searchaction=1&search_type=proc

I can only see i.MX233 being in non bga packaging

Answer (score 2):

Allwinner A13 offers Cortex A8 in TQFP ( Similar to LQFP )

http://olimex.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/cortex-a8-in-tqfp-sure-allwinner-a13/

http://www.allwinnertech.com/product/A13.html

Datasheets : from Olimex github

https://github.com/OLIMEX/OLINUXINO/tree/master/HARDWARE/A13-PDFs

https://github.com/OLIMEX/OLINUXINO/tree/master/HARDWARE

Comment: Can you give us a bit more details as to why this processor specifically is useful?